# Azure Maps not loading in Angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-maps

I'm trying to add Azure Maps to a simple Angular app.

I get the error below. Any idea why it happens and how I can fix it?

```
atlas.min.js:2509 Error: AuthenticationManager finished initializing, but no token is available
    at atlas.min.js:2509
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:365)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:40794)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:851
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:40772)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
```

The steps I have followed to add it are:

1 - Install Azure Maps

```
npm i azure-maps-control
```

2 - Create a component for the map

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AddressSearchService } from '../address-search.service';
import { AddressSearchJson, AddressSearchResult } from '../address-search-result.model';
import { Map, AuthenticationType, HtmlMarker } from 'azure-maps-control';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-search',
  templateUrl: './address-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-search.component.css']
})
export class AddressSearchComponent implements OnInit {


  // Azure Active Directory Authentication Client ID
  // or Shared Key Authentication KEY
  // get it from portal.azure.com
  key: 'sharedKeyPrimaryKey';
  map: any;


  ngOnInit(): void { 
        // Initialize a map instance.
    this.map = new Map('mapContainer', {
      authOptions: {
        authType: AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey,
        subscriptionKey: this.key
      }
    });

    // Wait until the map resources are ready.
    this.map.events.add('ready', () => {
      // Create a HTML marker and add it to the map.
      this.map.markers.add(new HtmlMarker({
        color: 'DodgerBlue',
        text: '10',
        position: [0, 0]
      }));
    });
   }

  constructor(private adressSearchService: AddressSearchService) { }
}
```

3 - Create the view

```
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>
```

4 - Modify angular.json

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.js"
            ]
```

5 - ensure that I'm using the correct Azure Maps key (Shared Key Authentication - Primary Key)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I believe I can help you on this! I had a lot of trouble getting Azure maps to work with Angular. I am fairly new to Angular and don't know exactly why your code gives that error but I know its something to do in your component because everything else is correct and is exactly how I have it. I have copied my component code for loading the map below in the hopes that it helps you.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as atlas from 'azure-maps-control';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-azureMap',
  templateUrl: './azureMap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./azureMap.component.css']
})

export class AzureMapComponent implements OnInit {
  // Azure Active Directory Authentication Client ID
  // or Shared Key Authentication KEY
  // get it from portal.azure.com
  key: string = 'your key';
  map: any;

  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //Initialize a map instance.
    this.map = new atlas.Map('mapContainer', {
      center: [-122.33, 47.6],
      zoom: 12,
      view: 'Auto',

      authOptions: {
        authType: atlas.AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey,
        subscriptionKey: this.key
      }
    });

    //Wait until the map resources are ready.
    this.map.events.add('ready', () => {
      //Create a HTML marker and add it to the map.
       this.map.markers.add(new atlas.HtmlMarker({
         color: 'DodgerBlue',
         text: '10',
         position: [0, 0]
       }));
    });
  }

}
```